# Configure PhpStorm to use Prettier for *.php files

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm, prettier

I've installed globally `prettier` and `@prettier/plugin-php` packages, and added `php` extention to Prettier preferences:
[image]

When I press `Cmd+Opt+Shift+P` in a `*.php` file editor, I've got this error:

> "Prettier: File *.php has unsupported type"

[image]

How to configure my PhpStorm to use Prettier for *.php files in my Wordpress project?

Comment: this can't be configured, only JavaScript, TypeScript, CSS, vue, markdown, JSON are supported. Please file a feature request to add `php` to the list of supported file types to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: was there ever a feature request made for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart phpstorm in order to have prettier able to run for php after you installed the plugin